# React Select with Async - Failing to load options

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I am attempting to create a [react-select](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select) async input field that provides model numbers based on user input. My API is working, as is the Fetch, which is producing the exact 'options' object required to populate dropdown (I checked both the network requests and the console).

The problem is that when I start typing, the dropdown shows that it is loading, but no options are added to it.

[image]

Here is an example output from the Fetch call: 
`{options: [{value: "WA501006", label: "WA501006"}]}.`

This is my code:

```
getModelsAPI = (input) => {

        if (!input) {
            return Promise.resolve({ options: [] });
        }

        const url = `(...)?cmd=item_codes_json&term=${input}`;

        fetch(url, {credentials: 'include'})
            .then((response) => {
                return response.json();
            })
            .then((json) => {
                const formatted = json.map((l) => {
                    return Object.assign({}, {
                        value: l.value,
                        label: l.label
                    });
                })
                return { options: formatted }
            })
    }

onChange = (value) => {
    this.setState({
        value: value
    })
}

<Select.Async
  value={this.state.value}
  loadOptions={this.getModelsAPI}
  placeholder="Enter Model"
  onChange={this.onChange}
/>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you need to return from the `getModelsAPI` function:

```
getModelsAPI = (input) => {

        if (!input) {
            return Promise.resolve({ options: [] });
        }

        const url = `(...)?cmd=item_codes_json&term=${input}`;

        return fetch(url, {credentials: 'include'})
            .then((response) => {
                return response.json();
            })
            .then((json) => {
                const formatted = json.map((l) => {
                    return Object.assign({}, {
                        value: l.value,
                        label: l.label
                    });
                })
                return { options: formatted }
            })
    }
```

Comment: Can you please explain why the need for 'return', isn't the return value of 'getModelsAPI' the output of Fetch?

Comment: `fetch` is a promise, which can be chained with multiple `.then()`s. Each return inside `fetch` passes the value to the next `.then()` down the line, but they don't return outside the function. For that, you need a return before the whole promise